# how to reduce memory use when doing parallel computations in a for loop

Tags: r, memory, parallel-processing

I'm having memory issues when using parlapply in a for loop.

Here is a toy example of what I'm trying to do.

```
nosim <- 5 #in reality at least 300
nosteps <- 10 # in reality at least 15
datalist <- datalistgrow <- as.list(rep(10,nosim)) #in reality this contains big datasets
simlist <- list()

for(i in 1:nosteps){
    ncores <- detectCores()
    cl <- makeCluster(ncores-1) #set up nodes
    out <- parLapply(cl,datalistgrow,function(x){
        fit <- lm(x~rep(1:length(x))) # fit a more complex model that takes ~5 seconds to run
         res <- coef(fit)[1] #do a whole bunch of calculations
        return(res)
    })
    stopCluster(cl)
    new <- lapply(datalist,function(x) rnorm(1,x,0.1)) #simulate data for the new time step
    datalistgrow <- lapply(1:nosim,function(x) c(datalistgrow[[x]],new[[x]])) #add new data to the list (in reality the amount of data only increases by about 2%)
    ... # calculate several statistics
    simlist[[i]] <- unlist(out) # put all statistics in a list
}
```

The problem is, after some timesteps I use up all of my memory and Rstudio stops working (and my laptop becomes tremendously slow...). Here is a print-screen of my memory usage history;

[image]

All "hills" represent a timestep and you can see the sharp drop after the cluster is stopped. I don't understand why with every new time step so much more memory is used when parlapply is always doing exactly the same thing, albeit being it on somewhat larger (~2%) data sets. I would expect my subsequent "hills" to be only marginally larger.

I rewrote my function so I don't save the actual model fits (heavy) but only small size derived quantities and I looked at e.g. cluster types, garbage collection, etc. to try and reduce memory use. I was however never able to completely solve or understand the problem.

Precisely, my questions would be:

1. Why does the parlapply part use so much more memory with every step in the for loop?
2. What can I do to avoid this
3. Is their a function in R that stops all calculations when around 95% of the memory is used, instead of having a crash?

Thank you

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
```

Comment: Do you know the size of all the objects you created? How much RAM do you have? Have you tried with `makeForkCluster`?

Comment: Yes, I always print the size of the 10 largest objects after each time step.  None of them is bigger than 1 GB (although 2 objects can get near). I have 32 GB of free RAM so I don't even understand how all of it can be used.... I'll try the function you suggest and see what that gives.

Comment: Fork clusters are not supported on windows, whether makeForkCluster is used or makeCluster with type fork.

Comment: Why do you create a new cluster for every iteration? I am not sure if it would help, but I would place creation and stopping of the cluster outside the loop.

Comment: Because the model fitting part that needs the cluster is in reality a separate function. Which function to use is an argument, and most don't need the clustering.

Comment: What version of R? If you're using R (< 3.3.2), then upgrade, because there in R 3.3.2 there was a fix that could lower the memory usage up to 50% in the workers created by the parallel(*) package, cf. https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/Wishlist-for-R/issues/27.  (*) I'm assuming you're not using snow::makeCluster(), because that's a different story. PS. It's always good to share your `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Interesting to know! I use a higher version though (edit to the question).